# Keep rows within a group untill condition is met in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am trying to filter the data within a group until a condition is met (in this case until status is "completed") and drop rest of the rows within a group. I've managed to come up with this ranking solution but I've ran into few issues with it when applying the code to my "real data". The function would sometimes not keep the last row (with max rank). Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Code i've used:

```
require(dplyr)

time <- seq(as.Date('2017/01/01'), as.Date('2017/01/15'), by="day")

set.seed(42); status <- sample(c("Completed", "On hold", "Active"), 15, replace = T)

ID <- c(rep(1, 5),rep(2, 5),rep(3, 5))


DF <- data.frame(Time = time,
                 Status = status,
                 ID = ID)

DF <- DF %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(ID_Rank = row_number())

DF$ID_Rank[DF$Status == "Completed"] <- max(DF$ID_Rank)+1

DF2 <- DF %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(row_number() <= which.max(ID_Rank))
```

Comment: `sample` results in some randomness. please use `set.seed` to allow for some reproducibility.

Comment: Done, but I wanted to test it under different conditions.